# What does it mean if my flag was "removed during a deletion"?

Tags: support, flags, deletion

I recently flagged a question as a duplicate of another question asked by the same user. When I go into my flagging history, it says that my flag was "removed during a deletion":

[image: screenshot]

I first thought that that meant that the post was deleted and then undeleted, so I went into the editing history of the post where it usually says things about deletion and I saw that the question was never deleted.

I looked in all the categories of flags on the right of my flagging history page ("waiting for review", "helpful", "declined", "disputed", "aged away", and "retracted") and the flag wasn't in any of them.

What does this "removed during a deletion" mean?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283463/missing-flag-in-flagging-history

Comment: @yellowantphil Yes, I just noticed that the other question was deleted.

Comment: Not exactly.  The post flagged by the OP is from a user that just keeps reposting the same crappy question.  The system should of course not dismiss these kind of flags so easily, this is a **bug**.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137440/rows-are-not-hidden-correctly-vba-please-heelp) as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098986/unable-to-hide-rows-correctly-vba) (10k-only link). But then, the second question - the target - was deleted. A question can't be marked as a duplicate of a question that has been deleted, for the obvious reason that we would then be directing users to a dead end.

Because the duplicate target has been deleted, your flag was removed before anyone could act on it. So, you get the message "removed during a deletion." This is, admittedly, not very clear. Something like "removed - duplicate target was deleted after flag was raised" would be much more clear.

See also [this handy explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283472/238426) over on MSE (hat tip to approxiblue for posting this [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339562/what-does-it-mean-if-my-flag-was-removed-during-a-deletion/339563#comment421405_339562)).

Comment: I don't mind, but why not add a link to post mirror? Some under-10k users would maybe find this helpful.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek What do you mean by "post mirror?" An image? It's not really relevant to the question what the deleted question said; the only important fact is that it was deleted after the flag was raised.

Comment: I meant a copy of the text of the post, possibly uploaded to pastebin or some other similar online site.

Comment: @rudolf Google crawls Stack Overflow pretty aggressively. This question is still in the cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?num=20&site=&source=hp&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41098986%2Funable-to-hide-rows-correctly-vba&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41098986%2Funable-to-hide-rows-correctly-vba But there's a reason why things are deleted. This isn't a hidden nugget of gold...

Comment: Just gone through the need to search the meaning of it due to not being clear and found this answer relatable (+1).