# NAA flags marked as "removed during a deletion"

Tags: bug, flags

Something I've never seen before is that my last six NAA flags have been marked as "removed during a deletion":

[image]

I wondered what circumstances could cause that to occur? These were just your typical NAAs not anything where any of the accounts or questions involved have been nuked. The only [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339562/what-does-it-mean-if-my-flag-was-removed-during-a-deletion) I've found here involves flagging a question as a duplicate when the target is removed which is understandable.

Comment: MSE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352697/294055

Comment: Interesting. The status we see on flags (via the post they were cast on) is 'EventInvalidated'. I hope these flags are still being marked helpful and not invalidated?

Comment: @Rob I just checked my profile and they're not listed under helpful, but they don't come up under declined or disputed either so they seem to go into limbo.

Comment: @PeterJ I suspect this is because the post was deleted (which used to mark flags helpful), rather than the flags being manually marked helpful. I've pinged a CM to look into this

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398687/deleting-and-undeleting-a-post-clears-all-comment-flags/400046#400046

Comment: It seems that "Not an Answer" flags can never be "helpful" under this new logic. If the post is deleted, the flag goes into limbo. If you want an outcome, it can only be: declined.

Comment: Definitely related. Apparently [this wasn't the plan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398687/deleting-and-undeleting-a-post-clears-all-comment-flags/400046#comment787769_400046). Being fixed now